# Downcasting generic of Future in dart

Tags: dart, casting

I have a future that has a generic parameter, which is a superclass (`A`) of another class (`B extends A`). I know for a fact that the instance of the value of the Future is of the subtype. Why can't I downcast the `Future<A>` to `Future<B>` in dart? If I unwrap the Future once and then wrap it again using async/await, it works.

Here's an example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A{}

void main() {
  Future<A> getFuture() async { return B();}
  Future<B> getBasA() { return getFuture() as Future<B>;}
  Future<B> getBasAasync() async { return (await getFuture()) as B;}

  print(getBasAasync()); // Works
  print(getBasA()); // Throws at runtime
}
```

For the curious and as a motivation for the question, here's a closer-to-world example. I have a stream that emits data packets, which I filter and then get the first like this:

```
Future<T> getResponse<T extends ReceivedPacket>() =>
  getStream<ReceivedPacket>().firstWhere((packet) => packet is T) as Future<T>; //throws

Future<T> getResponse<T extends ReceivedPacket>() async { //works
  return (await  getStream<ReceivedPacket>().firstWhere((packet) => packet is T)) as T;
}
```

PS: I've tried it out in [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oAcCuAjEBLY0BmA9gQFzQB2qAtugKYBO0AvNAKwDc0AvgFCiQwAhaDQAeAFxpkAJjFhI0mHNHRg6pCGLpYyAcyYBySFLz62PbpACeZXHlQ2xWAmWg6aYgAp0ClLBBoAFACUpF4%20fjQAPLAAfIjQdO6odC5kNADu0ALBZtx2Dk4ubmICkLDBod6%20-pECcUiJYslF7mHVgUHQkNBtEbUxuVY2%20PbAjs6u7qUQsEPAFT1VfXXxjc3QAWDpYFhik55L-sGd3QK5FhDWtqPjLpQ7ZMGI3NDQwM4QBCA0AHQgBDoApttrt9tNZpcbMcfio6EE2C83h8vr9-oDgTs9sVwdDYfDuOZuPdtDkgA) (will happily compile and run) and [C#](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nKzoCC6A3gL6EzoBCIJlBSAkG24QMyY1YDsyMs3SY4ANkwAOTGIA8xAHzoA5gFMALgDEAruu0AnVQAoAlCLKY+6AHaqA7nVO4qSEVglQ5tJWvW0AhgDOxKbklioaOnqGoUEyst7OyG7iUvHeEX5BxFCSphZQVkZQAJyZUQbGJmZxtEmsyCywMI1CSMmiJUa+AcG5pgB0AOIaACoAngAOVQOjAPYAyur6AJbWyqYmuOgA9DvoAOpz+gDWgR1YXT3ZgyPqE9OD80ur65vbe+ijABb6c3aBdD+dTofTaazqFYAW1UjRcFCAA==) (won't compile, but I have very limited C# knowledge). I understand that the answer to this question might be "because this is how the dart type system works". I'm just confused, because I'd have expected it either to fail at compile time like C# or work at runtime, too, like typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `getFuture()` as returning `Future<A>` but with the `async` keyword, so Dart automatically transforms `return B();` to (essentially) `return Future<A>.value(B());`.  The returned `Future` was never a `Future<B>` and therefore cannot be downcast to it.

Creating the `Future` explicitly would do what you expect:

```dart
Future<A> getFuture() { return Future<B>.value(B()); }
```

You could argue that Dart when transforms `return x;` in `async` functions, it should create a `Future<T>` where `T` is the static type of `x` instead of inferring it from the function's return type.  As lrn explained in comments, that can't be done because you might have:

```dart
class C extends A {}

Future<A> getFuture() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

  if (Random().nextBool()) {
    return B();
  } else {
    return C();
  }
}
```

The caller must get a `Future` back immediately, but it won't be known whether its value will be a `B` or `C` until the `Future` eventually completes.

> I'd have expected it either to fail at compile time like C#

I too have very limited experience with C#, but I think that C# gives you a compilation error because C# does not consider `Generic<SubType>` to be a subtype of `Generic<SuperType>` whereas Dart does.

Comment: The reason Dart doesn't make the returned future's type depend on the `return` statement is that an `async` function returns a future *immediately* when called (synchronously), and that future is later completed when the body returns. The type of the returned future must be chosen before you know when `return` statement will eventually do the return, so it must be an, in this case, `Future<A>` which is returned.